# JMS Provider to connect to AWS SQS using .bindings

Tags: java, jms, aws-sqs-fifo

We are looking for moving our solutions to start using AWS Simple Queue Service instead of Rabbit MQ.

Now we are using JMS to connect to our queues using a .bindings file to configure the jndi context to connect.

Is it possible to use a .bindings file to configure the connection to AWS Simple Queue Service configuring the region, using a profile as parameters, all configured inside the .bindings file?

If yes do you have any example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the RabbitMQ JMS client uses `.bindings` is because it relies on `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory` as the [`InitialContextFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory.html) implementation.

From what I can tell the Amazon SQS JMS client has no support for JNDI at all. There are no references or examples in the documentation that use JNDI. They all use programmatic creation.